# Objective c - How do you use the resume function in Mac OSX lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion

In mac OSX Lion, a new feature was introduced, for the user to be able to pause all their applications on shut down and resume them when they turn their computer on again.

My Question is what you need to do to achieve this compatibility (e.g when you have a file open in a text editor) with resume as i have seen photoshop CS5 isn't compatible with resume.

Is there any guide on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, check out the [Resume and Automatic Termination in Lion](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=119) WWDC session.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [high-level guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26) in Apple's documentation.

(This isn't the sort of thing you can add to someone else's application after the fact, if that's what you were hoping for.)

Comment: no it was for my own, thanks for this resource, will check it out